# How to use PYTHONPATH to import the whole folder in Python

Tags: python, import, pythonpath

I am new to python and trying to add a project folder to the PYTHONPATH. I created a .pth file and add my root path of the file in my site-packages folder. However, when I trying to import the .py files in this folder, only those located under the root folder (for example '/sample') can be imported, but those subfolders under the /sample folder were not able to be imported (for example /sample/01). So my question is what file and how to change it to make my whole folder including all its subfolders can be importable.

In the worst case I can think of is to write down all the folders name in the .pth file in site-packages. But I just believe that Python will provide a more efficient way to achieve that.

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, you'd want `sample/a.py`, `sample/x/b.py`, and `sample/y/z/c.py` to be importable as `import a,b,c`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had occasion to ever use a *.pth* file. I prefer a two-pronged approach:

- Use a *shebang* which runs *env python*, so it uses the first *python* on your path, i.e.:

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

- Use *virtualenv* to keep separate different environments and group the necessary libraries for any given program/program set together. This has the added benefit that the *requirements* file (from *pip freeze* output) can be stored in source control, and the environment can be recreated easily anywhere, such as for use with *Jenkins* tests, et al.

In the *virtualenv* case the *python* interpreter can be explicitly invoked from the *virtualenv*'s *bin* directory.

For local modules in this case, a local *PyPI* server can be used to centralize custom modules, and they can also be included in the *requirements* file (via the --extra-index  option of *pip*).

**Edit with response to comment from OP:**

I have not used *SublimeREPL* before, however, based on the scenario you have described, I think the overall simplest approach might be to simply *symlink* the directories into your *site-packages* (or *dist-packages*, as the case may be) directory.

It's not an ideal scenario for a production server, but for your purposes, on a client box, I think it would be fine. If you don't want to have to use the folder name, i.e. `import ch1/foo`, you'll need to symlink inside of those directories so you can simply `import foo`. If you're OK with using the dir name, i.e. `import ch1/foo`, then you should only need to *symlink* the top-level *code* directory.

Comment: Thanks for your instruction Ken, but its kinda hard for me to understand at this point. I think I should give more background: I am using SublimeText3 with REPL. I already set SublimeREPL to use my desired python interpreter /home/myname/anaconda/bin/python. I am studying textbook Building Machine Learning Systems with Python. The source code are place according to chapters in separate folders: ch01, ch02, etc. They all under one main folder /code. So what is the best way to import the folder /code so that i can use all files in it regardless specify the sub folder name and the path?